# normed division algebra

Tags: ring-theory, division-algebras

Can we prove that every division algebra over $R$ or $C$ is a normed division algebra?
Or is there any example of division algebra in which it is not possible to define a norm?
Definition of normed division algebra is in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_division_algebra). Thanks!

Comment: A transcendental extension field?

Comment: sorry. I cant understand. can you explain me little more clearly.

Comment: I am guessing a transcendental extension field is a division algebra but not normed division algebra. but can you tell me why it is true? thanks.

Comment: Related: [Existence of norm for C*-Algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/404256/79365)

Answer (score 5):

[**Frobenius theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) for (finite-dimensional) *asscoative* real division algebras states there are only $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}$, and  the proof is elementary (it is given on Wikipedia in fact).

If you don't care about finite-dimensional, then the transcendental field extension $\mathbb{R}(T)/\mathbb{R}$, where here $\mathbb{R}(T)$ is the field of real-coefficient rational functions in the variable $T$, is a divison algebra (it is a commutative field) but cannot carry a norm. Indeed, there are no [infinite-dimensional normed division algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45653/infinite-dimensional-normed-division-algebras).

Finally, there are real division algebras that are not $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}$ or $\mathbb{O}$ (which are the only normed ones), which means there are division algebras that cannot carry a norm. It is still true they all must have dimension $1,2,4$ or $8$ (see section 1.1 of Baez's The Octonions), but there are (for example) uncountably many isomorphism classes of two-dimensional real division algebras (but unfortunately I don't have a reference for this handy).

Comment: I am interested to hear more about what you mentioned in the last paragraph, so I made a separate question over here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892818/finite-dimensional-division-algebras-over-the-reals-other-than-mathbbr-math