# What are some important non-normable topological vector spaces?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Among all those non-normable(even better if not even metrizable) topological vector spaces, which are the ones that are of special interest or very useful (in math or other subjects)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075222/is-there-such-thing-as-an-unnormed-vector-space#1075236 mentions a few examples.

Comment: Simple and important examples are the various spaces of test functions used to construct distributiona, like the Schwartz space and others. Similarly, the space of C^\infty functions on a manifold has an important topology, the Whitney topology, which does not arise from a norm. Once you understand these examples it is easy to construct many others. In topology one likes also the space $\mathbb R^{(\infty)}$.