# Finite dimensional division algebras over the reals other than $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},$ or $\mathbb{O}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers, division-algebras

Have all the finite-dimensional division algebras over the reals been discovered/classified?

The are many layman accessible sources on the web describing different properties of such algebras, but all the ones I have come across seem to stop short of fully restricting them to $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},$ or $\mathbb{O}$, yet do not mention the existence of anything beyond those four.

The wikipedia page on [division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) mentions that any finite-dimensional division algebra over the reals must be of dimension 1, 2, 4, or 8. 
 It also mentions the only finite-dimensional division algebras over the real numbers which are alternative algebras are the real numbers themselves, the complex numbers, the quaternions, and the octonions. (And [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/normed+division+algebra) claims we don't even need the finite-dimensional qualifier for the last statement.)

[Hurwitz's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurwitz+theorem) tells us that these are also the only normed unital division algebras over the reals.

So any finite dimensional division algebra over the reals other than $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},$ or $\mathbb{O}$ cannot have a norm if it is unital, nor have a matrix representation, nor even be alternative.  Are there any known examples?  Have all the possibilities been classified?

Comment: Inspired by this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2154089/432537 which mentions there exist some 2 dimensional real division algebras other than the complex numbers.

Comment: I couldn't help noticing that the related nLab pages don't agree with each other in the relevant definitions. For example, their definition requires that a division algebra should also be a division ring. And (one click further) their definition of a division ring requires associativity, contrary to specifically stating that a division algebra need not be associative. Anyway, I'm too fond of associativity to think about your question. I would ping the arctic tern for comments.

Comment: I don't recall about classifying general non-associative algebras, but some examples are given by doubling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction

Comment: classification of 2D division algebras over the reals is discussed in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2894443/432537

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Real division algebras have not been classified.  The best known result is the classification of flexible division algebras, which is found in [this paper](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:308352/FULLTEXT01.pdf) by Darpo.  Some more details can be found in [this survey paper](http://www.kirj.ee/public/proceedings_pdf/2010/issue_1/proc-2010-1-53-59.pdf) (also by Darpo), where he states that the general classification is not known.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) on division algebras, there are infinitely many non-isomorphic division algebras of dimension $2$ over the reals. One example according to Wikipedia is the product being defined as the conjugate of the usual complex number product.